# Вывод данных в uicollectionView из json

Tags: json, objective-c, uicollectionview

Доброго времени суток. Приходят данные о погоде в json, не понимаю как их хранить, чтобы потом можно было вывести в uicollectionView.

```
daily =     {
    data =         (
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "42.23";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491305400;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "33.21";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491269400;
            cloudCover = "0.88";
            dewPoint = "38.05";
            humidity = "0.97";
            icon = rain;
            moonPhase = "0.27";
            ozone = "351.85";
            precipIntensity = "0.0054";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.0103";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1491244200;
            precipProbability = "0.51";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1025.27";
            summary = "Drizzle in the morning.";
            sunriseTime = 1491271151;
            sunsetTime = 1491316979;
            temperatureMax = "45.66";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491305400;
            temperatureMin = "33.21";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491269400;
            time = 1491247800;
            windBearing = 263;
            windSpeed = "3.77";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "60.62";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491391800;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "32.55";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491348600;
            cloudCover = "0.22";
            dewPoint = "31.52";
            humidity = "0.65";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-night";
            moonPhase = "0.3";
            ozone = "361.94";
            precipIntensity = "0.0004";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.0024";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1491334200;
            precipProbability = "0.07000000000000001";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1027.5";
            summary = "Partly cloudy in the morning.";
            sunriseTime = 1491357462;
            sunsetTime = 1491403433;
            temperatureMax = "60.62";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491391800;
            temperatureMin = "32.55";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491348600;
            time = 1491334200;
            windBearing = 29;
            windSpeed = "0.64";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "71.04000000000001";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491478200;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "34.31";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491435000;
            cloudCover = 0;
            dewPoint = "28.99";
            humidity = "0.43";
            icon = "clear-day";
            moonPhase = "0.34";
            ozone = "342.14";
            precipIntensity = 0;
            precipIntensityMax = 0;
            precipProbability = 0;
            pressure = "1018.94";
            summary = "Clear throughout the day.";
            sunriseTime = 1491443773;
            sunsetTime = 1491489887;
            temperatureMax = "71.04000000000001";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491478200;
            temperatureMin = "37.83";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491435000;
            time = 1491420600;
            windBearing = 128;
            windSpeed = "3.41";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "70.64";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491564600;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "35.6";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491528600;
            cloudCover = "0.05";
            dewPoint = "29.26";
            humidity = "0.39";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-night";
            moonPhase = "0.38";
            ozone = "315.47";
            precipIntensity = 0;
            precipIntensityMax = 0;
            precipProbability = 0;
            pressure = "1011.36";
            summary = "Mostly cloudy overnight.";
            sunriseTime = 1491530084;
            sunsetTime = 1491576341;
            temperatureMax = "70.64";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491564600;
            temperatureMin = "40.74";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491528600;
            time = 1491507000;
            windBearing = 164;
            windSpeed = "6.85";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "69.98";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491647400;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "46.45";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491615000;
            cloudCover = "0.43";
            dewPoint = "34.29";
            humidity = "0.42";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.41";
            ozone = "313.26";
            precipIntensity = "0.0004";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.0008";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1491629400;
            precipProbability = "0.01";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1011.75";
            summary = "Mostly cloudy in the morning.";
            sunriseTime = 1491616396;
            sunsetTime = 1491662795;
            temperatureMax = "69.98";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491647400;
            temperatureMin = "48.82";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491615000;
            time = 1491593400;
            windBearing = 238;
            windSpeed = "5.2";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "64.09999999999999";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491726600;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "45.62";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491762600;
            cloudCover = "0.96";
            dewPoint = "37.35";
            humidity = "0.54";
            icon = rain;
            moonPhase = "0.44";
            ozone = "325.93";
            precipIntensity = "0.0049";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.0143";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1491733800;
            precipProbability = "0.5600000000000001";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1013.76";
            summary = "Light rain starting in the afternoon, continuing until evening.";
            sunriseTime = 1491702709;
            sunsetTime = 1491749249;
            temperatureMax = "64.09999999999999";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491726600;
            temperatureMin = "45.62";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491762600;
            time = 1491679800;
            windBearing = 244;
            windSpeed = "5.51";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "65.33";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491823800;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "41.11";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491780600;
            cloudCover = "0.1";
            dewPoint = "37.11";
            humidity = "0.59";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-day";
            moonPhase = "0.47";
            ozone = "332.28";
            precipIntensity = "0.0009";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.002";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1491841800;
            precipProbability = "0.05";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1015.96";
            summary = "Partly cloudy starting in the afternoon, continuing until evening.";
            sunriseTime = 1491789022;
            sunsetTime = 1491835703;
            temperatureMax = "65.33";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491823800;
            temperatureMin = "41.11";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491780600;
            time = 1491766200;
            windBearing = 296;
            windSpeed = "1.25";
        },
                    {
            apparentTemperatureMax = "57.05";
            apparentTemperatureMaxTime = 1491910200;
            apparentTemperatureMin = "40.03";
            apparentTemperatureMinTime = 1491935400;
            cloudCover = "0.24";
            dewPoint = "37.94";
            humidity = "0.65";
            icon = "partly-cloudy-night";
            moonPhase = "0.51";
            ozone = "344.71";
            precipIntensity = "0.0017";
            precipIntensityMax = "0.0021";
            precipIntensityMaxTime = 1491899400;
            precipProbability = "0.05";
            precipType = rain;
            pressure = "1018.87";
            summary = "Mostly cloudy starting in the evening.";
            sunriseTime = 1491875335;
            sunsetTime = 1491922158;
            temperatureMax = "57.05";
            temperatureMaxTime = 1491910200;
            temperatureMin = "43.34";
            temperatureMinTime = 1491935400;
            time = 1491852600;
            windBearing = 272;
            windSpeed = "6.57";
        }
    );
    icon = rain;
    summary = "Light rain today and Sunday, with temperatures rising to 71\U00b0F on Thursday.";
};
flags =     {
    "isd-stations" =         (
        "386470-99999",
        "387500-99999",
        "387550-99999",
        "387560-99999",
        "387590-99999",
        "387630-99999",
        "387670-99999",
        "387740-99999",
        "407210-99999",
        "407230-99999",
        "407350-99999",
        "407380-99999",
        "407390-99999"
    );
    "madis-stations" =         (
        OINE
    );
    sources =         (
        gfs,
        cmc,
        fnmoc,
        isd,
        madis
    );
    units = us;
};
latitude = "37.617633";
longitude = "55.75578";
offset = "4.5";
timezone = "Asia/Tehran";
```

}

[image: кастомная ячейка] есть кастомная ячейка и ее IBOutlet'ы

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *weatherIcon;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

PatternViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PatternCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSString *myString = [self.arrayImagesForCollectionView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.weatherIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myString];
cell.cellLabel.text = myString;


// Format 12:42 PM based on User Settings
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[self.weatherForcast.time integerValue]];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

cell.timeLabel.text = currentTime;



return cell;

}
```

Знаю что можно десериализовать в массив или словарь, а как потом вывести все "time", "apparentTemperatureMin", "icon" из каждого блока ?

Comment: После того, как Вы десериализовали данные в массив, вы можете получить доступ к нужному элементу в массиве через `indexPath `(например`array[indexPath.row]`), Вы получаете элемент под нужным индексом. Тут зависит как у вас реализован массив, это массив словарей или же вы создали класс/структуру. `NSDictionary * item = array[indexPath.row], NSString * apparentTemperatureMax  = item["apparentTemperatureMax"]`

Comment: @VitaliEller 
`NSURL *weatherURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url]; 

NSData *date = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:weatherURL];

NSDictionary *jsonDate = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:date options:0 error:nil];

NSDictionary   *dailyjson = [jsonDate valueForKey:@"daily"];

NSDictionary *jsontime = [dailyjson valueForKey:@"time"];

  ` Я вот так записываю, но это не правильно как я понял

Comment: Да, это не верно. Посмотрите лог чему равен `NSDictionary *dailyjson = [jsonDate valueForKey:@"daily"];` Там содержиться еще один ключ `data`. Вам надо сделать еще один шаг `NSDictionary *data = [dailyjson valueForKey:@"data"];` и вот теперь `NSDictionary *jsontime = [data valueForKey:@"time"];` должно сработать

Comment: Да, точно, моя невнимательность. Спасибо, все записывает.

Comment: Добавил ответ =)

Comment: Я вам отмечу, это 100% ) Если не сложно есть еще вопрос. Не первый раз сталкиваюсь. Как проделегировать так чтобы пока данные не придут не рисовать тот или иной view ? так получается, что uicollectionview рисуется до того как я записал данные в массив и вывел.

Comment: Тут сложнее, collectionView рисуется сразу из сториборда, но попробуйте во viewDidAppear обновить collectionView. Так же можете попробовать создавать completionHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary *dailyjson = [jsonDate valueForKey:@"daily"];` Обратите внимание, что там содержиться еще один ключ `data`. Вам надо сделать еще один шаг `NSDictionary *data = [dailyjson valueForKey:@"data"];` и вот теперь `NSDictionary *jsontime = [data valueForKey:@"time"];`